# Typing Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))

Tags: typescript, forms, javascript-objects, typescript-generics

TypeScript newbie here, having problems with `Object.fromEntries`. I'm trying to pares form and cast its values to something else. For example, given homogeneous shape of all data being strings, below works:

```
// example form content:
// {
//    foo: 'bar',
//    bar: 'biz'
//  }
//  return values
// {
//    foo: 'bar',
//    bar: 'biz'
//  }

export const getFormData = (form: HTMLFormElement) => {
  return Object.fromEntries<string>(
    new FormData(form) as Iterable<[PropertyKey, string]>,
  )
}
```

How I can cast values returned from the above to values others than strings? For example:

```
// example form content:
// {
//    foo: '1',
//    bar: 'biz',
//    biz: 'false'
//  }
//  desired return values
// {
//    foo: 1,
//    bar: 'biz',
//    biz: false
//  }

export const getFormData = (form: HTMLFormElement) => {
  return Object.fromEntries<string>(
    new FormData(form) as Iterable<[PropertyKey, string]>,
  )
}
```

My feeling is that I can *somehow* fix it with generics and interfaces but I'm at a loss how to proceed. If someone could ELI5 I would be grateful.

EDIT: my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
        "target": "es2020",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "preserveValueImports": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Better explanation of the desired outcome.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAjMZW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  In this case it probably means that you should call your function and show how the behavior differs from what you expect.

Comment: As it stands you are going to get an object whose value types are `FormDataEntryValue`, which is `string | File`.  You seem to be ignoring the possibility of `File`, and then I'm not sure where you expect conversion from `string` to happen.  You have said "cast" a few times, but the term is ambiguous (it means different things to different people) and best avoided.  TypeScript has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and these are more like *observations* than *actions*.

Comment: If you say `"1" as number` you're telling the compiler "I know you think that `"1"` is a `string`, but actually it's a `number`."  (It would probably complain about that.)  It doesn't turn `"1"` into a `number`.  TS's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types), so `"1" as number` will compile to `"1"`.  If you want to actually have runtime effects you need to write code that does it, like `+"1"`, which compiles to `+"1"`, and evaluates to `1` at runtime.  (This is also not called "casting", but *coercion*).

Comment: Am I addressing your issue here or am I missing something?  I could maybe write up an answer (assuming you provide a [mre]) but I want to be sure I understand the situation.

Comment: Your explanation is great! This is actually non-issue anymore, it was my incomplete understanding of how TS works.

Comment: I don't see how the answer you accepted addresses your question.  If the question is a non-issue, maybe you should delete it.  Otherwise it will be here as a resource for future readers, and it would be nice for the q/a pair to make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your TS config add "dom.iterable" to `lib`:

```
"lib": [
  "es2019",
  "dom",
  "dom.iterable"
],
```

Now that TS knows that the DOM element can return an `.entries()` iterator, you don't need to type it explicitly anymore:

```
Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))
```

Since you're using an HTML form, you won't get anything but strings and blobs. If you want to convert some of the strings to numbers, casting won't help you. Just iterate the entries, and convert values that fit a certain criteria - for example a certain key, or if converting them to numbers doesn't produce `NaN`. For example ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWwCIEMrpgXhmAUwHcYAxJNTdACgEoBuAWACgWEUMsA6dAB14JgAJtQDkYdMgKiANDFHJ0AD1EM2FTuh79BI0egDm0uaICMAJgDMAFgCsANlVNWzUJFiICEAK4AbWHgA8gBGAFYEwFBccIggyACiYFCIAJZe1ADaXNnslFgAulyKvNSZANYEAJ5yAG7ovt4E%20bS4AHwwGSwwMBXVXT1VuDh4%20kaiMAD8MADUdQ0EMABcMHONLM20LCxuECC%20BFy%20IAbUnj7%20tEA)):

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', 'max');
formData.append('age', '123456');

const result = Object.fromEntries([...formData].map(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  key === 'age' ? +value : value
]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I do have that set (OP updated).

Comment: Have you removed all types and try to let TS infer the types?

Comment: And another problem - FormData can only include strings (all standard form fields) and blobs (files) as values.

Comment: I did remove all other types. And you're absolutely right about strings and blobs! I didn't know that. But I can cast those values as something else with 'new FormData(form) as ...', no? This is what I'm after, sorry if I wasn't clear - I'll adjust the OP.

Comment: Since you're using an HTML form, you won't get anything but strings and blobs. If you want to convert some of the strings to numbers, casting won't help you. Just iterate the entries, and convert values that fit a certain criteria - for example a certain key, or if converting them to numbers doesn't produce `NaN`.

Comment: Man, that actually makes perfect sense. I might need more coffee. Write is as a standalone answer and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: This answer has been accepted but it doesn't look like it actually addresses the question directly.  Could you [edit] it to be about "casting" (the preferred term here is *asserting*) not having any runtime effect?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to set `dom.iterable` in your `tsconfig.json` you could do something like:

```
const handleFormSubmit = (evt: SubmitEvent) => {
  const form = evt.target as HTMLFormElement;
  const formData = new FormData(form) as unknown as Iterable<
    [RequestData, FormDataEntryValue]
  >;
  const requestData: RequestData = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(requestData);
};
```

Where `RequestData` is an interface like:

```
interface RequestData {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  biz: string;
}
```

You will then have completions on your `requestData` identifier. And the compiler won't yell.